# How to perform a join query using Symfony and Doctrine Query Builder

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have two entities which are connected through a 1:1 relationship, e.g: `MyEntity.idRelatedEntity`
I want to create a Doctrine query where I can retrieve data from `MyEntity` depending on a value from a certain column in `RelatedEntity`. Something like this (it doesn't work of course):

```
$entity = $em
    ->getRepository('MyBundle:RelatedEntity')
    ->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->leftJoin('MyBundle:RelatedEntity', 'r')
    ->where('r.foo = 1')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Where are you writing this query ? It would help me to answer your question AND improve your code. is that in the `MyEntityRepository` ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$entity = $em
    ->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')
    ->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->join('e.idRelatedEntity', 'r')
    ->where('r.foo = 1')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Also left join makes no sense here (because of where clause that will make it work like inner join)

Comment: Great! Thank you! Just a small correction, you missed the id part inside the join. It should read `->join('e.idRelatedEntity', 'r')`

Comment: can you please tell from where this r come?

Comment: `->join('e.idRelatedEntity', 'r')`, here you define `r` as an alias, you can put whatever here

Comment: `idRelatedEntity` is the name of the main table **column which related to other table,  Ex for product table** related field  is  **category** so then  the join will be `->join('e.category', 'r')`

Answer (score 18):

Note that you should write this query in your `MyEntityRepository`

```
public function getMyEntityWithRelatedEntity($parameter) 
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->addSelect('r') // to make Doctrine actually use the join
        ->leftJoin('e.relatedEntity', 'r')
        ->where('r.foo = :parameter')
        ->setParameter('parameter', $parameter)
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

And then use it in your controller/service :

```
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$results = $manager->getRepository(MyEntity::class)->getMyEntityWithRelatedEntity(1);
```

Comment: Nice one (and cleaner). Will take into account for the next time. For now I'm using @Uriziel answer :) Thank you!