# Using an Inner Join with QueryBuilder on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, join

I want to use an inner Join for my tables auto and rent('s'). Its an 1:N relationship. If I use `->innerJoin('s', 'a')` it comes to some errors like this:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 62 near 's a, ChrisKfzBuchungBundle:Auto': Error: Class 's' is not defined.

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ChrisKfzBuchungBundle:Rent');

$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('s');
$qb->from('ChrisKfzBuchungBundle:Auto', 'a')
    ->where('s.mieteStart >= :date_from')
    ->andWhere('s.mieteEnde <= :date_to')
    ->setParameter('date_from', $date_from)
    ->setParameter('date_to', $date_to);
```

How do I join one ore more tables with queryBuilder?

Comment: see if it's solve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357159/how-to-perform-a-join-query-using-symfony-and-doctrine-query-builder

Comment: i tried this post already, it doesnt seem to be supported in the actual symfony 2 version

Comment: and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354401/using-join-in-symfony2-doctrine-sql

Answer (score 2):

There are methods for that and also for me it just worked with a configured relation between the two entites. Here are two working examples:

left join:

```
$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('s')
    ->leftJoin(ChrisKfzBuchungBundle:Auto', 'a', 'WITH', 's.id = a.yourJoinCOlumn')
    ...
```

inner join:

```
$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('s')
    ->select('s, a')
    ->innerJoin('s.yourJoinColumn', 'a')
    ...
```

Comment: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 90 near 's a WHERE s.mieteStart': Error: Class 's' is not defined. please post the complete code. where in your left join is a definded?